How is it justified to treat the EM field as a classical function in deriving the Mott scattering fomula?
We know that the scattering cross-section of an electron from the static Coulomb field of a nucleus (given by the Mott formula) can be obtained from QED but treating the electromagnetic field, $A^\mu(t,\vec{x})$, not as a quantum field operator but as a classical function. When is this justified? Neglecting the recoil of the nucleus allows us to assume that the potential $A^\mu(t,\vec{x})$ is time-independent (static) potential. But how is it justified to treat it as a classical function?
